# How to get the new Size of a ViewGroup when its children change visibility?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have a `ConstraintLayout`. Give a set of condition the `ConstraintLayout` children changes visibility and so the `ConstraintLayout` also change size overtime. I want to animate this size changes but I don't know how to get the new height of the `ConstraintLayout` when a child (or any number of them) changes visibility?

I tried measuring the `ConstraintLayout` but I could not get the correct size. Can someone guide me here?